# Is there any English Translation of Yechaveh Da'at by Rav Ovadia Yosef

Tags: jewish-books

Is there any English translation of Yechaveh Da'at, I know Yalkut Yosef is in English.

Answer (score 2):

There is no English translation of Yechaveh Da'at. You can however find volumes among the author's work such as Chazon Ovadiah and Anaph Etz Avot translated into other languages. If you prefer to read along in Yechaveh Da'at with a narrator, you can begin with volume one [here](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLz446Z0vWtQUXHbFYmp5voax0SlwTHAEJ).

What makes Yalkut Yosef appealing in translation is it's unique dual form layout in which the upper section is a lucid text without numerous scholarly references. This is not available by definition in Yechaveh Da'at.

Comment: Thank you, I find this helpful

Comment: Good luck to you